# How to store file with unicode characters using paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I'm using paperclip gem to process some images and store them to Amazon S3. Each image represents person's name. I want to add support for names with unicode characters as well, but I can't make it work because of paperclip fails to upload a file with unicode characters in its name.
I can't just change Ñ to N before uploading, because then I'll overwrite an image that was uploaded with letter N.
Eg.
Two users: NUÑO and NUNO. I can't just tell paperclip to upload NUÑO.jpg as NUNO.jpg because that will overwrite previous NUNO.jpg.

Here's my pretty much standard production/staging environment configuration:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :url => ':s3_domain_url',
  :path => 'assets/:class/:id/:style.:extension',
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
  }
}
```

And here's related class with image attachment:

```
class NameSpread < ActiveRecord::Base
(...)
  has_attached_file :rendered_image,
    default_url: lambda { |attach| attach.instance.processing_image },
    path: lambda { |attach| attach.instance.save_path },
    styles: { (..) },
    processors: [ :name_spread_processor ],
    default_style: :spread
(...)
end
```

Here's save_path method:

```
def save_path
  if Rails.env.production? || Rails.env.staging?
    "assets/:class/#{gender}/#{name}/:style.jpg"
  else
    "#{Rails.root}/public/assets/:class/#{gender}/#{name}/:style.jpg"
  end
end
```

This is the part that gets messed up: `#{name}`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days of debugging, I found the solution.

I updated from ruby 1.9.2 to 2.0.0 and now everything works...